Constructing a Basis for Polynomials with the Given Point $\gamma(1) = 0$
I understand the definition of a basis and have no issue constructing them for problems involving vector spaces and subspaces. I know the basis of the polynomial vector space ($P$ = {$p_1$, $p_2$,$...$,$p_n$}) in its simplest form can be expressed as $S$ = {$1,x,x^2,x^3,…,x^n$}.
I'm unsure how this translates to the following problem and my professor's hint that dim$(\Gamma) = 2$ has only left me further confused.
Let $\Gamma$ be the subspace of $\Bbb P_2$ consisting of polynomials of the form:
$$\gamma(x) = ax^2 + bx +c$$ $$a,b,c \in \Bbb R$$ $$\gamma(1) = 0$$
Construct a basis for this space and prove that your choice of functions is indeed a basis.

Further hint: if $\gamma(1) = 0$, then $a + b + c = 0$, i.e. $c = -a - b$. So, the polynomials in this space take the form $ax^2 + bx - a - b$. Can you find two non-parallel polynomials that span the polynomials of this form?

If the space only consisted of the polynomials of the form $$\gamma(x) = ax^2 + bx +c,\quad a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$$
Then we simply have $n=2$ and a basis would be $\{1,x,x^2\}$.
However, the fact that $\gamma(1)=0$ further restricts this space. This condition implies that $$a+b+c=0\implies c=-a-b$$
Substituing yields $$\gamma(x)=ax^2+bx-a-b=a(x^2-1)+b(x-1)$$
So $\{x^2-1,x-1\}$ is a generating set for our subspace, and a simple argument proves this is a linearly independent set, and thus a basis.

Hint:

You can first convince yourself that $\mathbb{P}_2$ is a vector space, and that $\Gamma$ is one as well.
You could choose the "standard" basis $\left(1,x,x^2\right)$ for $\mathbb{P}_2$ (expressing $\gamma$ as $(a,b,c)$), but that's not convenient for the condition $\gamma(1)=0$.
So, try to find conditions on the coefficients to satify that condition. What is thus the dimension of $\Gamma$?
Now, can you find $\dim\Gamma$ polynomials that are linearly independent?

